# "[webpack-cli] configuration[2].entry should be one of these" error when used function as value for entry object in one of configs

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, build, bundle

I'm using Webpack 5.88.2.

In one of configs inside my `webpack.config.js` I'm trying to use a method that sorts various files from `./dist` directory with bundles built during running other configs and after sorting, returns the array of strings, which are paths to needed files.

The array of strings is to be used as entry point of this particular config.

But I keep getting error:

```
[webpack-cli] Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration[2].entry should be one of these:
   function | object { <key>: [non-empty string, ...] (should not have fewer than 1 item, should not have duplicate items) | non-empty string | object { import, asyncChunks?, baseUri?,
 chunkLoading?, dependOn?, filename?, layer?, library?, publicPath?, runtime?, wasmLoading? } } | [non-empty string, ...] (should not have fewer than 1 item, should not have duplicate 
items) | non-empty string
   -> The entry point(s) of the compilation.
   Details:
    * configuration[2].entry['mma'] should be one of these:
      [non-empty string, ...] (should not have fewer than 1 item, should not have duplicate items) | non-empty string
      -> Module(s) that are loaded upon startup.
      Details:
       * configuration[2].entry['mma'] should be an array:
         [non-empty string, ...] (should not have fewer than 1 item, should not have duplicate items)
         -> All modules are loaded upon startup. The last one is exported.
       * configuration[2].entry['mma'] should be a non-empty string.
         -> The string is resolved to a module which is loaded upon startup.
    * configuration[2].entry['mma'] should be an object:
      object { import, asyncChunks?, baseUri?, chunkLoading?, dependOn?, filename?, layer?, library?, publicPath?, runtime?, wasmLoading? }
      -> An object with entry point description.
    * configuration[2].entry['mma'] should be one of these:
      [non-empty string, ...] (should not have fewer than 1 item, should not have duplicate items) | non-empty string | object { import, asyncChunks?, baseUri?, chunkLoading?, dependOn
?, filename?, layer?, library?, publicPath?, runtime?, wasmLoading? }
      -> An entry point with name.
```

I don't understand why this error happens, if the `entry` property in documentation allows usage of method to populate entry points.

Use same method inside node script and it return the array of strings flawlessly.

Here's the part of config with said entry method:

```
entry: {
    'mma': function() {
      return fs.readdirSync(
          __dirname.split('\\')
              .filter((part) => part !== 'modules')
              .join('\\') + '\\dist'
      )
          .sort((a) => {
            if (a.startsWith('v')) {
              return -1;
            } else if (a.startsWith('c')) {
              return 1;
            } else {
              return 0;
            }
          })
          .map((path) => './dist/' + path);
    },
  },
```

When I change it to:

```
const fs = require('fs/promises');

const generateFilePaths = async () => {
  const filePaths = await fs.readdir(
      __dirname.split('\\')
          .filter((part) => part !== 'modules')
          .join('\\') + '\\dist'
  );
  console.log('filePaths', filePaths);
  return filePaths.sort((a) => {
    if (a.startsWith('v')) {
      return -1;
    } else if (a.startsWith('c')) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }).map((path) => './dist/' + path);
};

entry: {
  'mma': () => generateFilePaths(),
},
```

I stil get the same.

Had anyone similar error?

Comment: `entry` should be a function or an object with `Record<string, string>`, not `Record<string, function>`. In the current documentation, I can't even find that functions are supported: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/ Can you share a link? Unrelated: The sort is broken if the array contains more than 2 elements either starting with `c` or with `v`.

Comment: In my particular case, there won't be more than one element each starting with `c` or `v`, so it may stay that way.

But regarding the docs, there's something like [dynamic entry](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/#dynamic-entry) which allows even `Promises`.
What my method returns is array of strings, where every string is a path to specific needed file, like `.html` or `.js`.

Comment: `entry` is either a function or an object that contains a string or objects. It's not an object of functions.